# Apache : Actual Version Released Date vs Server Built Date?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, versioning

In my Linux, i have `httpd` (Apache2), and i was curious about it's version released date. So i did:

# httpd -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 15 2015 15:50:14
```

But when i google about "Apache 2.2.15 Released Date", according to Apache official version announcement archive, it was released since `06 Mar 2010` which is terribly OLD.

Ref:

[image]

So please let me understand which DATE is my Apache actually updated to?

Thank yo all! :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using RHEL/CentOS 6.x, as it uses Apache 2.2.15 as the base version.

The whole idea with RHEL and its derivates is that during a life-cycle of one major release the software versions do not change at all. Instead the severe bugs are fixed by backporting them and all kinds of small enhancements (such as support for new hardware) are made.

So, the original release date for your Apache is from 2006, but the build has been modified a lot since then compared to original release.